# web page app screen shot images scrolling problem while refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css

*this is my webpage*

*I am facing an issue in my webpage have you seen apps screenshots are displayed in the websites that can be scrolled left and right I have implemented it but the problem is when I click refresh page the functionality stucked if I again refresh it works okay after again I refresh making issues again  tried  refreshing same issue means not scrolling the screenshot images*

*the style make the images to place in correct position*

*Actually I am running this code in vs code and I am using live server extension

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Doodle+Shadow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.7.2/lottie.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      
        .container-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .movable-container {
            display: flex;
            white-space: nowrap;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
            /* Add smooth transition effect */
        }

        .movable-container img {
            margin: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 400px;
            border-radius: 30px;
        }

        .move-button {
            /* position: fixed; */
            top: 50%;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .move-left {
            left: 10px;
        }

        .move-right {
            right: 10px;
        }

        #left:hover {
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        }

        #right:hover {
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <section>

//here is the code that i face some issues while refreshing 
        <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
            <img src="left1.svg" alt="left" class="move-button move-left" id="left" onclick="moveLeft()">
            <div class="container-wrapper">

                <div id="image-container" class="movable-container">
                    <img src="UI (3).jpeg" alt="track">
                    <img src="UI (1).jpeg" alt="track1">
                    <img src="UI (2).jpeg" alt="track2">
                    <img src="UI (4).jpeg" alt="track3">
                    <img src="UI (5).jpeg" alt="track4">
                    <img src="UI (6).jpeg" alt="track5">
                    <img src="UI (7).jpeg" alt="track6">
                    <img src="UI (8).jpeg" alt="track7">
                </div>

            </div>
            <img src="right3.svg" alt="right" class="move-button move-right" id="right" onclick="moveRight()">
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 Your Health App. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>
    <script>
//this is the javascript code that makes the images to scroll while clicking the left and right //buttons 
        const container = document.getElementById('image-container');
        const images = document.querySelectorAll('.movable-container img');
        let scrollPosition = 0;
        const imageWidth = images[0].offsetWidth + 20; // Including margin
        const totalWidth = imageWidth * images.length;

        function moveLeft() {
            // Move content to the left
            scrollPosition -= imageWidth;
            if (scrollPosition < 0) {
                scrollPosition = 0;
            }
            container.style.transform = `translateX(-${scrollPosition}px)`;
        }

        function moveRight() {
            // Move content to the right
            const maxScroll = totalWidth - container.offsetWidth;
            scrollPosition += imageWidth;
            if (scrollPosition > maxScroll) {
                scrollPosition = maxScroll;
            }
            container.style.transform = `translateX(-${scrollPosition}px)`;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```